# Corrupted Mongo Archive

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, mongodump, mongorestore

Recently I tried to take a backup from my current database using `mongodump --archive`. Since the *MongoDB* had deployed as a docker container and the backup command used `docker exec -it`, the dumped archive includes miscellaneous characters and unfortunately it can't be restored by `mongorestore`. You can check the backup command at below:

```sh
docker exec -it <CONTAINER> sh -c 'mongodump -d db --archive' > db.dump
```

Since the database is not available now, I need to restore the corrupted archive. At first attempt I tried to remove extra obvious characters manually but it wasn't enough. Then I decided to use *Python* to parse the archive but I couldn't neither serialize it as a `bson` nor decode the bytes.

Here it's a part of the archive which is read by *Python* as a binary file:
`...\x85\x01\x00\x00\x02db\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00example\x00\x02collection\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00...`

What's your suggestion for this issue? Do you know what is the encoding of `mongodump --archive` output? Any response would be appreciated...